# Specify platform for Docker image in Visual Studio Code DevContainers

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

I'm using a MacBook Pro with the M2 processor (`arm64`) but I need to start a devcontainer with an `amd64` version of the Python image (**buster**):

**Docker image**: [mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/python:0-3.11-buster](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/main/containers/python-3)

This is what I've tried so far:

### Add `platform` in the Dockerfile

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/python:${VARIANT}
```

### Setting the `DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM` environment variable in `.zshrc`

```
DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64
```

### Set `runArgs` in `devcontainer.json`

```json
  "runArgs": [
    "--platform=linux/amd64"
  ],
```

But for all of them I receive the following error when building the container:

```
[183642 ms] Start: Run: docker inspect --type image mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/python:3.11-buster
[185190 ms] Error fetching image details: No manifest found for mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/python:3.11-buster.
[185190 ms] Start: Run: docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/python:3.11-buster
3.11-buster: Pulling from vscode/devcontainers/python
no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries
[186436 ms] []
[186436 ms] Error response from daemon: No such image: mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/python:3.11-buster
```

How can I fix the platform to `linux/amd64`?